# RGB LED strip green LEDs cannot be dimmed to less than 50%

Tags: arduino-uno, led, led-strip

I have an RGB LED strip which I want to control with my arduino uno, everything works fine, except for the green LEDs.
They cannot be dimmed to less than 50%, because they will simply turn off.

I have this test code in my setup:

```
Serial.write("dimming green test started");
for(int x = 255; x > 0; x--) {
    analogWrite(greenPin,x);
    Serial.write(" - g:");
    Serial.print(x);
    delay(6);
  }
  Serial.println();
  Serial.write("dimming green test done");
  Serial.println();
```

And the green LEDs are fully turned on in the beginning, and at about 127, the just turn off. All the other colors are perfectly dimmable.
I checked the energy usage, and green does only use a little more than the other colors, so that's not the problem.

**Are green LEDs not dimmable? Or is this just an optical effect?**

(I use a setup very similar to this one with one difference: but only use 5V, because my LED strip only needs 5V) [image: setup]

Comment: switch connections at arduino. swap pin 4 and 7 ... does the problem move to red color?

Comment: the pins marked with `~` are the PWM pins ... use those

Comment: so why does blue and red work :p

Comment: I used pins 5-7 (so the image was not exactly correct)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`analogWrite` only works on pins that support PWM. Those are the pins with the `~` next to it.

On no-PWM pins, analogWrite will set the pin to LOW, for all values lower than 128, and HIGH for all the higher values. Which is what you are experiencing.

Comment: interestingly, none of the 3 pins chosen by the OP - 2,4 and 7 - have that ~ symbol in the image in the question!

Comment: @JaromandaX the OP said the image was from a similar project, so I’m not assuming he used those exact pins.

Comment: `with one difference` - well, there's **three** connections to LED's, but only one fails to work ... must be at least **two** differences between actual wiring and what OP shows in the question :p

Comment: I used pins 5-7, so only one of them was not PWM